# I try to get Contacts in Microsoft Graph and receive exception Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I try to get Contacts in Microsoft Graph and receive exception

> Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);
var result = await graphClient.Me.Contacts.GetAsync();
```

Comment: In the second line there should be Id "var result = await graphClient.Me.Contacts["{contact-id}"].GetAsync();" , refer document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request

Comment: No, It is correct